# Entity Framework code first not working

Tags: entity-framework, entity, ef-code-first

I have a Class like this:

```
class ClassA
{
    public long classAID {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<ClassB> ClassBs {get; set;}
}

class ClassB
{
    public long classBID {get; set;} 
    public string SomeOtherDescription {get; set;}

    public IEnumerable<ClassA> {get; set;}
}
class TestContext: DBContext
{
    public DbSet<ClassA> ClassAs {get; set;}
    public DbSet<ClassB> ClassBs {get; set;}
}
```

H have the DB with same column names and table names as the classes and properties.
I have done the web.config configuration as required. When i try to use above to retrieve the data i get the error

```
"System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'ClassA' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType."
```

and

```
"System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'ClassB' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType."
```

I tired multiple approaches such as setting the key attribute, Foreign key attribute etc. but nothing worked. Please let me know what am i missing.

I use C# 4 and i have verified with following URLs: 
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-4

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx

Comment: does the tables in db have primary keys defined properly?

Comment: Yes i have primary keys defined. classAID  and classBID  are primary keys and tableB has  the attribute classAID which is a FK

Comment: The code you posted works as expected so there must be problem elsewhere.

Comment: Btw. if you want to define relation you cannot use `IEnumerable`, you must use `ICollection`

Comment: @Ladislav, now i have put [Key] for ClassAID and ClassBID and changed IEnumerable to ICollection. the query which it internally calling was pointing to ClassAs and i corrected that. data loads for ClassA but the child table data is not getting loaded. i get null. for the property public ICollection<ClassB> ClassBs {get; set;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public long ClassAID {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<ClassB> ClassBs {get; set;}
}

public class ClassB
{
    public long ClassBID {get; set;} 
    public string SomeOtherDescription {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<ClassA> {get; set;}
}

public class TestContext: DBContext
{
    public DbSet<ClassA> ClassAs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ClassB> ClassBs { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see navigation properties are marked as `virtual`. It will allow lazy loading = navigation property will be loaded separately first time your code access the property. It is not always the best way to load navigation properties this way because it causes additional roundtrips to the database. Because of that EF also offers eager loading where you explicitly tell EF to load your navigation property:

```
var query = context.ClassAs.Include(c => ClassBs);
```

Comment: I actually could not get the above working. :( i generated the classes from my db using EF power tools(http://goo.gl/5NiuH). Now it works fine

Comment: And what was the difference between code you tried and the code the tool generated for you?